# Error code 0x800705070 when deleting some files

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I have a few files on my hard drive that when I try to delete I get a message saying:

> An unexpected error is keeping you from deleting the file. If you
>   continue to receive this error, you can use the error code to search
>   for help with the problem.
>
> Error 0x800705070: The file or directory is corrupted and readable.

I know the files aren't blocked. How should I delete these files?

Comment: Have you checked the disk for corruption? (by using chkdsk.exe for example)

Answer (score 0):

If [chkdsk](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-vista/how-to-use-check-disk-in-windows-vista/) does not repair the corruption and allow you to delete the file, boot from an Ubuntu CD and run the "Live" version, then delete the files from there.

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/) for backing up windows files using Ubuntu boot CD, it can also be used to delete files.